# Regex in postgres to extract datetime from text column

Tags: regex, postgresql

I have a column that has multiple comments along with some DateTime stamps. The example is like this:

```
abc@gmail.com - 03/03/2022 13:04:40
Documents Pending
Some random comment
```

I want to extract only the DateTime stamp from this column. I tried using to_char, and to_date functions in PostgreSQL, but none of it seems to work for me.
I also tried writing a regex to extract the DateTime stamp, but it didn't work.

What is the correct way to extract only DateTime from the above column? What would be the regular expression to extract the DateTime?
Thanks in advance.

Edit: I want to extract a date from a column like this:

```
abc@gmail.com - 12-Aug-2022
Documents Pending
Some random comment
```

How we can identify the month number or a date format from this comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `SUBSTRING()` here:

```sql
SELECT col,
       SUBSTRING(col FROM '\y\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\y') AS ts
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: can you provide some solution to the edit?

Comment: Yes, use: `\y\d{1,2}-\w{3}-\d{4}\y`

Comment: To catch the original format _or_ this format, use an alternation with the two patterns separated by `|`